# Yosemite mail notification delay

Tags: mail.app

I use gmail will the OS X mail app. When I get a new email, there's about a five minute delay until a notification appears. It's instant on my android phone.

I can check for new mail every minute. Is it possible to make it instant?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It simply takes time for Gmail to notify your Mac mail, and it can not be instant.

However if you must have Instant notification, then open your Gmail in a web browser and go to gmail settings.

In gmail settings you can enable instant notification (you get it as soon email arrives, but you will get it in the browser window, as well later in your mac Mail.

It works great with Chrome web browser, there will be a pop up on your scree when new email arrives.

[image: gmail]

Comment: But it says "You need to be signed in to Gmail and have Gmail open in your browser in order to see desktop notifications" With the mail app, you don't need to keep gmail in the background all the time.

Comment: If you want a INSTANT notification then yes. You can not get it faster in mail since the Google server has to send it to you first, while if you use the browser window you are already at the source.

Comment: My experience is that Google's own apps communicate much faster with Gmail (using their APIs) than generic apps (e.g. Apple's Mail.app) do using IMAP.